# Histogram with base 2 logarithmic y-scale in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Is there any way of doing this? The `hist` command doesn't seem to recognise it when I try and specify `base` or `basey`.

Comment: Could you post what you've already tried?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: The solution below works with matplotlib version <1.3.1.

---

Use

```
ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
mu, sigma = 100, 15
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)
ax.set_yscale('log', basey=2)
n, bins, histpatches = ax.hist(x, 50, facecolor='green', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @twch: Thanks for suggesting an edit. There appears to be a regression in matplotlib version 1.3.1 which causes only the top of the bars to be plotted. Unfortunately, I have to revert your edit (using `log=True`) because it also changes the y-axis scale to log base 10, instead of log base 2, which is the primary problem this SO post is trying to solve.

Comment: Please report things like this as bugs.

Comment: And it seems to be fixed on master, which will become 1.4.0 'shortly'.